# Problem with python arcade on new M2 MacBook

Tags: python, arcade

I am starting to learn Arcade and I had trouble running the following simple script on a new M2 MacBook. The loop never runs. Funny thing is that it runs without the while loop. The code runs smoothly both on my windows PC and my old Mac (both using the same python version). I am completely clueless as to what the issue might be. Could it be the new chip?

```
import arcade
import random

class Ball:

    def __init__(self):

        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0

        self.size = 5

        self.color = [10,0,0]
        

    def create(self):

        arcade.draw_circle_filled(self.x, self.y, self.size, self.color)
        
arcade.open_window(800,800,'ball')
arcade.set_background_color(arcade.color.WHITE)
arcade.start_render()

ball_1 = Ball()

while True:
    
    random_x = random.randrange(0, 800)
    random_y = random.randrange(0, 800)
    random_color_1 = random.randrange(0, 256)
    random_color_2 = random.randrange(0, 256)
    random_color_3 = random.randrange(0, 256)
    random_color = [random_color_1,random_color_2, random_color_3]

    ball_1.x = random_x
    ball_1.y = random_y
    ball_1.color = random_color
    ball_1.size = random.randrange(10, 30)

    ball_1.create()

    arcade.finish_render()

arcade.run()
```

Comment: How does the code execution ever get out of the `while True` loop so that `arcade.run()` can be called?

Comment: Thanks, Jeremy. As far as I understand, arcade.run() has no influence in the loop, it just keeps the window open.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `class` approach (which is recommended way to build `arcade` apps — see [starting template](https://api.arcade.academy/en/latest/examples/starting_template.html)):

```
import arcade
import random


class App(arcade.Window):
    def on_draw(self):
        arcade.draw_circle_filled(random.randrange(0, 800), random.randrange(0, 800), random.randrange(10, 30), [random.randrange(0, 256), random.randrange(0, 256), random.randrange(0, 256)])


App()
arcade.run()
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This works beautifully. But what is really puzzling to me is why my (terrible) script works on my other computers and not on the new MacBook. Anyways, thanks for the answer!